# Tomcat7 stops automatically on ubuntu

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7, ubuntu-server

Tomcat7 stops automatically and showing this error 
On running command

sudo service tomcat7 status

```
 Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You follow this post.You will

```
[Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists. What does this message mean? Do I need to recover Tomcat if I get it?][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In  `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml` comment this line

```
 <Context path="/lni" docBase="/dspace/webapps/lni" allowLinking="true"/>
```

Then restart tomcat.